# Can Tomcat 6.0 be monitored by Netcool

Tags: tomcat6, monitoring

I am currently working on an confluence upgrade project and will be migrating from Weblogic to Tomcat 6.0. At the moment all the monitoring of the whole system is done by Netcool. Does anyone know if I can monitor Tomcat 6.0 using Netcool?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd be amazingly surprised if it couldn't... I'm pretty sure netcool is built off of Tomcat 5.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor Tomcat you can use IBM Tivoli Composite Application Manager for J2EE. Remember that Netcool (I'm sure you meant Omnibus from the Netcool Suite), is the Event Management System, not the Monitoring tool.

You will need to use the IBM Tivoli Monitoring infrastructure for the ITCAM Agent, and configure the Event destination (Netcool Omnibus).